# How Can I Make Ansible Shell Tasks Idempotent?

Tags: ansible

I am taking over an ansible playbook that is used for deploying and upgrading an application.

The playbook takes hours to run and isn't idempotent in multiple places due to things like shell tasks, sql, dependencies etc.

I have tags in place to restrict parts of the playbook but I would prefer to have a way to make each task idempotent.
e.g.

```
- name: Add release application config
  become: yes  
  shell: "./applicationConfig.sh"
  tags: upgrade

- name: Add release database config
  become: yes  
  shell: "./databaseConfig.sh"
  tags: upgrade
```

Is it possible to do something like create a file when the task is successful and only re-run it/mark it as changed if the file doesn't exist?

On top of that, would it be possible to do this in one place and have it apply to all tasks in each play to reduce repetition and clutter in each task?

Comment: First question: of course. Using a mark file that you would create yourself (`args / creates`), checking presence for another file that may have been created as a result to your shell command, ... or even: run a first command, with `changed_when: False` + `failed_when: False`, registering a variable, then run your actual shell command only if your previous check confirms some action needs to be taken. Second question: maybe creating an tasks file that you would include (`include_tasks`), setting variables designating your command, mark file, ... whatever may change, dealing with all your cmds

Comment: [Playbook error handling - defining "changed"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-changed)

Comment: The key is how to make the mark file at the end of each successful task

Comment: It'd be better if you shared code that way we can recommend changes.  As you haven't done this, my recommendation is to create "get" tasks that register true or false to a variable then add when conditions to the "set" tasks based on the boolean state.  Good luck.

Comment: @Colyn1337 I'm not sure why you need an example of a shell task running a script but I added one anyway just in case you don't know what one looks like.